# How to check if a person has duplicate date records?

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I am looking to query my Access database from Excel (DAO) to determine if any name in the table has more than one record per date. E.g. If Bob has two records on 05/05/17 then I want to return both records as part of a recordset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT count(*), name, date 
    FROM yourtable
    GROUP BY name, date
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) multi
ON multi.name = yourtable.name
AND multi.date = yourtable.date
```

The inner select returns rows with more than 1 entry for the same name and date.

Comment: Thank you, this is great!

Answer (score 1):

In Access you can do

```
select name, date
from your_table
group by name, date
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: but this will just return the name-date combination with multiple entries.
if i understood right, he also wants to list all of those multiple recors.

Comment: This is great if I only need one instance returned.